# .htaccess: redirect all pages except one not working

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to get a redirect working for all pages, with wildcard, except one specific case. I 'have tried the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?old\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/menu
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.new\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

What I'm expecting is

```
old.com -> new.com
old.com/abc - > new.com/abc
old.com/menu -> old.com/menu
```

All redirects are working fine, except:

```
old.com/menu -> old.com/http://www.new.com
```

and I can't figure out why.

EDIT: the rest of .htaccess

```
RewriteOptions inherit
# Use PHP5.4 as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php

# For security reasons, Option followsymlinks cannot be overridden.
#Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?old.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /web/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?old.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ web/ [L]
```

Comment: Do you have anything else in your .htaccess file?

Comment: Added the rest of the contents.

Comment: `RewriteOptions inherit` - what is this for? This implies that you have mod_rewrite directives in a parent config file that are required - so this could also be a source of conflict? It might be better to post your .htaccess file(s) in their entirety, with the new directives in-place. (The order of directives is important.) There's no `RewriteEngine` directive, so what you have posted is not entirely complete.

Comment: I do have `RewriteEngine on` right at the beginning of the file, but everything else, I have included above. The edited part was already present in the file (I'm just editing the site, from a previous build) and there is no other `.htaccess` file in the parent directory. Removing the `inherit` options also doesn't seem to help.

Comment: There is "something else" going on here. The redirect you mention (`old.com/menu` to `old.com/http://www.new.com`) could not possibly be caused by the directives you have posted. In fact, I'm not even sure how you would do such an erroneous redirect in the Apache config (ie. htaccess). Likewise, anubhava's suggestion should not produce the result you are seeing - in fact, this doesn't appear to have made any change at all. Make sure all browser caches are clear - if you've experimented with incorrect 301 redirects then these will have been cached by the browser.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I haven't been able to figure it out and even reached out to Bluehost's CS (where the site is hosted), but they were not helpful at all.

Comment: What happens when you temporarily remove your .htaccess files entirely? (Make sure you clear your browser cache.)

Comment: I did find another `.htaccess` in a deeper folder that also has a redirect in it. Disabled that and it finally started to work using the below answer. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Ah haa! :) If that was a mod_rewrite redirect in the deeper folder then it would have overridden _all_ the mod_rewrite directives in the parent folder, unless you had `RewriteOptions inherit` in the deeper .htaccess file (although that wouldn't have worked properly anyway looking at the substitution paths in the parent .htaccess file). (mod_rewrite inheritance works differently to other modules.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this rule based on `THE_REQUEST` variable:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?old\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/menu [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.new.com/$1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: With this, old.com/menu only goes to new.com

Comment: This rule will completely skip `/menu` URLs. You either have bad cache in browser or some other conflicting rule.